# Cron job won't run on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a simple shell script that runs fine when opened in terminal, but will not run at all as a cron job!

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sshfs example.com: /mnt
/usr/bin/rsync -az -v --progress -h --delete /mnt/html/ /home/user/html/
/bin/fusermount -u /mnt
```

Any reasons why this shouldn't work?
I'm new to Ubuntu and Cron so it might be something simple.

Thanks!
(I added the job via the cron GUI, "Scheduled Tasks")

Comment: Any information in the logs?

Comment: Did the task get added to a user-based crontab, or to the root one?

Comment: @BobS Currently it is in a user-based crontab, but I've also tried the root one.

Comment: @CarlNorum The log outputs a message every time "Grandchild failed with exit status 1"

Comment: I don't know what causes the problem but I think you could avoid `sshfs` and simply use `rsync -e ssh -avz ...` instead. No need to mount and umount a remote filesystem.

Comment: @dschulz it's for backing up a GoDaddy hosting account. They don't allow rsync directly over ssh. :(

Comment: I see. You could try adding a simple function to your script to log all return values to a file. `function logthis() { echo "$*" >> /somewhere/cronjob.log }` and then add a line before and after each command gets executed: `logthis "about to execute sshfs.."` and after: `logthis "sshfs retval was $?"`

Comment: You'll probably need to change `#/bin/sh` to `#/bin/bash`

Comment: What are you using for sshfs credentials?

Comment: this question is better suited for "ask ubuntu" or "supersuer". ask this question there as that forum would be the right resource for you.

Comment: For **rsync** prefer to use `rsync -e "ssh -e none" ` instead of `sftpfs`. Mostly if target host could run `rsync` localy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` directly with ssh, without fuse/mount.

```
rsync -az -v --progress -h --delete example.com:/mnt/html/ /home/user/html/
```

But anyway, I suppose that the problem in your case is with the ssh keys.
You must check which keys are used when ssh start from `cron`. And configure ssh so, that it will use correct keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this

```
    #!/bin/sh
    . /home/<user>/.profile
```

crontab is independent you might need certain profile details.